# How change a CGContext attribute after drawRect is carried out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I draw a path using CGContext.

How can I later change one of the path attributes after drawRect was carried out (completed)? I want to be able to change the color of my path according to a slider value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defined the property and added [setNeedsDisplay] during property change did the deed ...

Answer (score 0):

To set color use this function

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, RED, GREEN, BLUE, ALPHA);
```

where RED, GREEN, BLUE, ALPHA, stands for float values from 0 to 1

Comment: tried to call a [UIColor clearColor] from my Object after drawRect was carried out (completed) but doesn't seem to work. How do you do it?